# Query that finds the names of the directors that played in movies that they directed

Tags: ms-access

Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies.

> Write in SQL query that finds the names of the directors that played in movies that they directed

[image]

**My attempt:**

```
 SELECT Directors.FirstName, Directors.LastName
 FROM Directors, DirectorsMovies,ActorsMovies
 WHERE Directors.DirectorID=DirectorsMovies.DirectorID=ActorsMovies.ActorID
 GROUP BY FirstName,LastName;
```

My code does not work well.